# is it possible to invoke a gitlab ci/cd step via rest call?

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-api

I'm new to gitlab ci/cd. Looking at the documentation, it suggests that we can define/set up ci/cd steps in our gilab pipeline . also , set up webhook integrations. is it possible to set up a step and invoke that by post request by a web call? in example below, I am aware that , i can automate the steps mention or invoke it manually from the browser. however, is it possible to invoke each step, like test-job1 and test-job-2 via a web call ?

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"

test-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  environment: production
```

I have set up a gitlab repo and added ci/cd steps in my gitlab ci file .

Comment: since none of these jobs have rules to conditionally trigger them if you trigger the pipeline from a web call all jobs will run. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [run a manual job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#run-a-job) using Gitlab’s API.

```
curl --request POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/1/play" \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>"
```

Your job would need “when: manual” added, or a rule that makes it be a manual job.

```
test-job1:
  stage: test
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"
```

In order to get the job ID you might need to perform additional API calls, like [list pipeline jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs). Be aware that you might need to paginate as it returns the last 20 pipelines. Here you get all manual jobs:

```
curl --globoff --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs?scope[]=manual"
```